# codeigniter csrf not work in select option

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, csrf

I want to make step input with select option, in this case, i make 3 step, when select first option then will show next option 2, then option 3. i am using ajax and i set $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE; in Codeigniter config file. In first select option (#kategori) is work and show next value in second select option, but in step 3 select option (#sub1 or secon function of javascript) n't work. thank before.

This is my view:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('',array('class'=>'form-horizontal'));?>
<?php echo form_label('Kategori','id_kategori',array('class'=>'col-sm-2 control-label'));?>
 <select id="kategori" name="id_kategori">
  <option value=""></option>
    <?php
     foreach($kategori as $kategori_umum)
      {
       echo '<option value='.$kategori_umum->id.'>'.$kategori_umum->nama_kategori.'</option>';
      }
    ?>
 </select>
 <select id="sub1" name="id_kategori_sub1"> //step 2
    <option value=""></option>
 </select>
 <select id="sub2" name="id_kategori_sub2"> //step 3
    <option value=""></option>
 </select>
```

Ajax :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#kategori').change(function(){
var kategori_id = $('#kategori').val();
    //alert(state_id);
if (kategori_id != ""){
    var post_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>masuk/produk/get_sub1";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: post_url,
        data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>','kategori_id':kategori_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(kategori_sub1, dataType) //calling the response json array 'kategori_sub1'
        {
            $('#sub1').empty();
            $('#sub1').show();
            $.each(kategori_sub1,function(id,sub1) 
            {
                var opt = $('<option />'); // creating a new select option for each group
                opt.val(id);
                opt.text(sub1);
                $('#sub1').append(opt);
                $('#sub2').hide();

            });
        },
        error:function(xhr)
            {
                alert("Terjadi Kesalahan");
            }
     }); //end AJAX
} else {
    $('#sub1').empty();
    $('#sub2').empty();
}});

$('#sub1').mouseout(function(){
var sub1_id = $('#sub1').val();
if (sub1_id != ""){
    var post_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>masuk/produk/get_sub2";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: post_url,
        data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>','sub1_id':sub1_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(kategori_sub2, dataType)
        {
            $('#sub2').empty();
            $('#sub2').show();
            $.each(kategori_sub2,function(id,sub2) 
            {
                var opt = $('<option />');
                opt.val(id);
                opt.text(sub2);
                $('#sub2').append(opt); 
            });
        },
        error:function(xhr)
            {
                alert("Kesalahan");
            }
     }); //end AJAX
}});</script>
```

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network. What is status? What gets returned? Need to narrow down where the problem is. Also using `mouseout` doesn't make sense...should be using `change`

Comment: i was try but it's same, when i set $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE; it's work. sorry I am not good in english.

Comment: Then you probably need a new csrf token each time. Return all the data as json...set and include a token to use for next request

Comment: i estimate it too, but i dont know to do it. and i inspect in browser and error is 403 forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is using wrong event `mouseout`.

You should be using `change` the same way the first one that works does.

Beyond that more information is needed about the actual requests by inspecting in browser dev tools

Comment: hey..that makes it easy then

Comment: $config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;